# How to automate a repetitive process using shell scripts

Tags: shell-script

So basically I need to run a command lets say `$ exampleCommand var1_1` and on completion of this command run `$ exampleCommand var1_2` then with `var2_1` etc.... I am running this on 50-60 files each at 90+gb so it doing this manually is not possible and I have never tried to automate something like this. Id appreciate some tips on how to go about doing this. I think I create a .sh file and then run it on the server im working on?

Comment: Does it matter if the command succeeds or fails?

Comment: It doesn't. I need it to move forward regardless, but the runs shouldn't fail at all since everything has been tested and the data checked endlessly

Comment: Are these var1_2 combinations existing filenames? Or numeric combinations that you need to generate based on ...?

Answer (score 2):

This should point you in the right direction:

```
$ for i in {1..3}; do for j in {x..z}; do echo ${i}_${j}; done; done
1_x
1_y
1_z
2_x
2_y
2_z
3_x
3_y
3_z
```

Comment: +1 for using `echo` statements to see what commands your code is generating _before_ actually executing the commands.

Answer (score 0):

The question you ask is a bit to global, and there are a lot of ways to automate specific tasks. The issue often comes in so many different file names, or regex match patterns. Please backup files before even running any script.

Just to get you going in a direction, see examples:

```
array=(file1 file2 file3)
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

user@workdir: # cd /dir && ls > ../files.list

```
main() {
    local list='/workdir/files.list'
    for item in $(cat "$list"); do
        func_read "$item"
    done
}

func_read() {
    local var="$1"
    [[ ! -d "$var" ]] && \
        while read -r line; do
            echo "$line"
        done < "$var"
}
main
```